# How to build CppUnit with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cppunit

I am trying to build CppUnit (first line in ReadMe says version 1.13) with Visual Studio 2010. Following the instructions (found on web forums, couldn't find much in CppUnit documentation); I cannot find a valid file extension. All file extensions end with ",v" what is this weird ",v" extension and what is the purpose of it?

I am frustrated at this point, if someone can help with how to load CppUnit in VS2010 project and build it....that would be a great help !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you referring to this project?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit

If so, use TortoiseSVN for example to get the latest code from svn:
https://cppunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cppunit

It contains "INSTALL-VS.Net2008.txt" with instructions for Visual Studio 2008 but it can also be applied to Visual Studio 2010.

You may have to edit src\msvc6\testrunner\MsDevCallerListCtrl.cpp and replace
`version("9.0")`
with
`version("10.0")`

You can safely ignore any build errors as long as the sln outputs cppunit(d).lib or whichever dependencies you need.

Have fun! :)

Comment: Rami, Thank you very much for the pointer. How come this site is not mentioned anywhere? BTW, I don't see TortoiseSVN there, but that's ok.

Comment: TortoiseSVN can be downloaded from here: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org.  You can use it to download the code from the cppunit source code repository.  It hasn't been updated in a while.  You can get more information about cppunit2 from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CppUnit.  You can also look into winunit, as I've recently used it with success: http://winunit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Update: the repository is now at https://svn.code.sf.net/p/cppunit/code/trunk and contains instructions and project files for Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully converted CPPUNIT 1.12.1 to be a VS2010 solution.  It's described here: http://blogs.powersoft.ca/erict/archive/2012/02/21/cppunit-in-vs2010ndashwith-a-sample.aspx and the solution can be downloaded from there.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a version which is really easy to build in VS2010(aka push 1 button):
http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3215/tools/cppunitAll.html

It's really nice because it has a .sln file which you can open directly. Also it includes a tutorial ;)
Found it with google.de 
It's version 1.12.1

Have fun!