# Getting started with CppUnit and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation, cppunit

I have searched for answers until I have become crossed-eyed and confused.

I have a Windows XP environment with Visual Studios 2010. I have downloaded and extracted CppUnit 1.12.1 from Sourceforge to C:\CppUnit. I understand I must use Visual Studio to open src/CppUnitLibraries.dsw and Batch Build all of the projects it opens to populate the lib directory with libraries. This is essentially the extent of the CppUnit "installation" process.

However when I try to open CppUnitLibraries.dsw, Visual Studio says the project must be converted to the current Visual C++ project format. If I click "yes" (to convert and open the project), it says the project file cannot be loaded and it asks if I want to remove the unloadable project from the solution, to which I say "No" since I'm certain this is not what I want to have happen. It does this for many projects in the CppUnitLibraries.dsw solution and I'm assuming this is unwanted behavior.

A few of my search results indicated that I should open src\msvc6\testrunner\MsDevCallerListCtrl.cpp, find the line that says...

`#import "libid:80cc9f66-e7d8-4ddd-85b6-d9e6cd0e93e2" version("7.0") lcid("0") raw_interfaces_only named_guids`"

...and replace the 7.0 with 10.0. But this does not help.

Am I doing something wrong? What must I do to get started with CppUnit? (I'm sorry if this is a very noobish question. I'm stuck, frustrated, and very confused.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build CppUnit with Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462852/how-to-build-cppunit-with-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully converted CPPUNIT 1.12.1 to be a VS2010 solution.  It's described here: http://blogs.powersoft.ca/erict/archive/2012/02/21/cppunit-in-vs2010ndashwith-a-sample.aspx and the solution can be downloaded from there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the extension .dsw was used by Visual Studio 6 in 1998.

By Visual Studio .NET 2003, they had moved to [.sln Solution Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Although the format has changed somewhat, Visual Studio 2010 still uses 2010 files.

So, if you've downloaded some software that comes with a .dsw file, Visual Studio 2010 will need to convert that file to a .sln to be able to use it.

Each time we've upgraded to a newer version of Visual Studio, at work, over the years, we've had to make some source code changes, for the newer compiler. So I'd say that any C++ code which comes with .dsw file is likely to require some significant effort.

I'd suggest trying to find a newer build or version of CppUnit, or looking for another tool.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462852/how-to-build-cppunit-with-visual-studio-2010) looks useful.